# Google Play device filtering working differently on two different APKs

Tags: google-play

I have a really strange problem. I have 2 apps in Google Play with very similar manifests. The only differences are that the other one has more "uses-permission" tags and also more activities/services. The one with more permissions etc can be installed on all the correct devices, as far as I can tell, but the one with less permissions reports "This application cannot be installed on your device" in Google Play for atleast two devices: Samsung GT-I9000 and Samsung GT-P6800. For example on my own phone, Samsung Galaxy Note (GT-N7000), both apps can be installed from Play.

The apps are:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ksatta.irop (The main app, with more permissions etc)

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ksatta.zradio.unlocker (The unlocker, with less permissions and activities/services)

Yesterday I tried setting "supports-screens android:anyDensity="true"" to the unlocker, since it was the only difference I thought might affect it. But the user reported that play shows the updated version, but still shows the devices as incompatible.

I found many questions about similar problems and the answers were usually to add support-screens stuff or something, but the main app doesn't have those either, so it can't be the problem.

Also the unlocker is paid and the app itself is free, but that shouldn't affect it?

Any ideas? It looks like a bug in Play's filtering?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there's a bug in the country list stuff in Google Play. The user's country is checked in my dev. console for the paid app, but http://support.google.com/googleplay/bin/answer.py?hl=en&topic=1046718&ctx=topic&answer=143779 doesn't have his country.

The strangest thing is that it kept showing him "not compatible" with his devices, even though the real problem seems to be his country.

Seems to be this : http://support.google.com/googleplay/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2677176

Issue first reported on: February 1, 2012
Last updated on: November 30, 2012

Come on Google.. seriously? 1 year and still not working??